# I want that id hide and show unique Id in Url using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/registration/invoice/<?php echo ($rows['id']);?>">

function invoice()
{
    $paymentid=$this->uri->segment('3');$record=$this->Registration_model->get_data($paymentid);
}
```

Comment: Show Unique ID. Means?

Comment: Means Random Id

Comment: Then, encrypt the ID in URL. And, Decrypt it in controller.

Comment: Sir Please Can you share the code complete code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create encrypted id with **base64_encode**

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/registration/invoice/<?php echo base64_encode($rows['id']);?>">

function invoice()
{
    $paymentid=base64_decode($this->uri->segment('3'));
    $record=$this->Registration_model->get_data($paymentid);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base64_encode can be decrypted easily.

Please add these two functions into your helper to encode decode the id:

```
function encode_url($string)
{

        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->library('encryption');
        $ret = $CI->encryption->encrypt($string);
        return str_replace(array('+', '/', '='), array('-', '_', '~'),$ret);

}

function decode_url($string)
{
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->library('encryption');
        $ret = str_replace(array('-', '_', '~'),array('+', '/', '='),$string);
        return $CI->encryption->decrypt($ret);
}
```

So you code will

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/registration/invoice/<?php echo encode_url($rows['id']);?>">

function invoice()
{
    $paymentid = decode_url($this->uri->segment('3'));

    $record = $this->Registration_model->get_data($paymentid);
}
```